# WordPress database error: [Query was empty]

Tags: database, wpdb

I'm using $wpdb to connect to a different database than my WordPress one like this:

```
$newdb = new wpdb(DB_NEW_USER, DB_NEW_PASSWORD, DB_NEW_NAME, DB_NEW_HOST);
```

I need to insert multiple rows into the database. I used the code from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373903/wordpress-wpdb-insert-multiple-records).

To run the query, I used the following code:

```
$newdb->query( $newdb->prepare("$query", $values));
```

When I did `echo $query`, this's the result: (there are more than 3 columns, but I shortened if for times sake)

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')
```

When I did `var_dump($values)`, it returned an array with the same amount of strings as I have columns.

When I ran the query, I got the following error:

> WordPress database error: [Query was empty]

I tried selecting from the database in a similar fashion and it did work, so my connection to the db is working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide us more code please?

Comment: Is your table actually named 'table'? And your column names are correct? Is `$values` an array of three elements?

Comment: Does it work if you use `$newdb->insert( $table, array( 'column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2', 'column3' => 'value3' ), array( '%s', '%s', '%s' ) );` in place of `$newdb->query( ... );` ?

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but I realized that I had an extra placeholder in the query. When I took it out, it worked.

Comment: can you split up your `$newdb->query( $newdb->prepare("$query", $values));` in 2 steps, and make a `var_dump()` on each? `$p_query = $newdb->prepare("$query", $values); var_dump($p_query); $result = $newdb->query($p_query); var_dump($result)`

Comment: Turn on the Debug Mode. Do the query manually using MySQL syntax just to verify that it's not a db problem(dont forget to add : `or die('Error : '.mysql_error())` to the query.